# Exploding probability under simple hierarchical Bayesian formulation

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

I am wondering if someone here can clear up a point of confusion that I have when applying MCMC or an optimization method to hierarchical Bayesian problems. Let's say we have a likelihood and prior with the following form:

$N(x_{i, j}|v_j, \sigma^2)N(v_j|\mu_v, \sigma_v^2)N(\mu_v|0, 1)p(\sigma_v)p(\sigma)$

Where $N$ represents a normal distribution, while $p()$ is some other unspecified distribution (e.g. half-normal). The subscript $i$ represents some repeated trial, while the subscript $j$ represents some grouping variable. For example $x_{i,j}$ is a button press time, where $i$ represents a single response for a subject $j$.
It seems to me that there are two ways to go to maximize the sum log probability here:

1. One is that $x$ constrains the individual $v_j$, which in turn constrains $\mu_v$ and $\sigma_v$ to their appropriate values.
2. Another is that $\sigma_v$ collapses to 0, (all) $v_j$ collapse to $\mu_v$, and sigma expands to cater to $x$. In this case, the log probability of $N(v_j|\mu_v, \sigma_v^2)$ explodes since all the $v_j$ are perfectly explained by $v_j = \mu_v$ and $\sigma_v=0$.

The solution that would be typically wanted is 1, but because of the 'exploding' nature of 2 I don't see how to avoid it in this formulation (without making strong assumptions about the priors). So I am wondering if the problem definition is simply not constrained enough or if I have a conceptual misunderstanding, or something else -

Thank you -

Comment: In this case, what does $v$ represent?

Comment: @LmnICE in the toy example I suggest, $v_j$ would represent the mean response time for an individual subject j (I happen to know that human response times are not truly Gaussian, but that is besides the point) - thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you object to making assumptions about the prior? Perhaps just a small concentration of the probability mass would nudge your model towards the right direction.

Comment: I didn't want to make the arbitrary choice of building into the model assumptions of how big sigma should be. In other words, I have no problem saying sigma = 0 is not OK, but  forcing the model to not approach sigma = 0... just seems ugly, maybe sigma is small... - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whether 1. or 2. happen depends on the specifics of the priors $p(v_j)$ and $p(\sigma)$.

In general, the Bayesian approach "shrinks" the specified likelihoods towards the priors. If the priors are "loose" (i.e. they assign non-negligible probability to a wide range of values), then the shrinkage is low and the likelihood dominates the posterior. If your likelihoods are also "loose", then the algorithms used to obtain the posterior through simulation (such as MCMC, HMC, etc) have a hard time.  In your case, 2. happens.

If on the other hand the priors are more specific, then the posterior is a mix between the likelihood and the prior. In that case, 1. happens.

To be precise, both 1. and 2. will happen, to the extent that the priors are more or less specific. The tighter they are, the more pronounced the effect of 1. on the posterior. Otherwise, the effect of 2. will dominate the posterior.

#### Response to comments

It seems as though you have little in the way of prior information about the free variables in your model (i.e. $\sigma _v$ and $\sigma$). Possible solutions are:

- Refactor your model so it depends on free variables about which you have a better intuition or more consistent prior information. For instance, refactor your model so the free variable is a general mean response time; in that case, you can set your priors based on a meta analysis, for instance; or
- Run a sensibility analysis to understand how much the posterior is influenced by the center of the probability mass on your priors. For instance, you can set up three cenarios:

  1. $\sigma _v$ centered around $10 ^{-3}$
  2. $\sigma _v$ centered around $10 ^{-2}$
  3. $\sigma _v$ centered aroung $1$

and see if they affect the posteriors too much.

Comment: I wonder if you meant $p(\sigma_v)$ and $p(\sigma)$, the problem is really a symptom of $\sigma_v$ going to 0. I agree with your points in general.

Comment: The specific answer that you give here to my question I think is - "problem definition not constrained enough". I don't particularly like this answer! - but I guess it's correct. I think my 'issue' is with the assumptions that have to be built into $p(\sigma_v)$ in order to avoid 2. Sure, we want something that avoids $\sigma_v = 0$, but how strongly do we need to penalize $\sigma_v = 10^{-3}$?, $\sigma_v = 10^{-2}$? (they would also cause huge posterior probabilities). It seems a bit hand wavy...

Comment: I understand your point about the apparent arbitrariness of the problem’s constraints. But these are the only free variables of your model. So one solution would be to refactor your model so it depends on free variables about which you have a better intuition. For instance, refactor your model so the free variable is a general mean response time; in that case, you can set your priors based on a meta analysis, for instance.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set up a sensibility analysis to check if the priors restraints impact your posteriors too much.